# DomParser fails to recognize white space between elements as text nodes in XML doc

Tags: xml, whitespace, element, between, domparser

I am using DOMParser, built into all modern browsers, to parse documents into XML. However, there is an issue with white space between elements. Thus this code:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("<p>Here is text <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>", 'text/xml');
```

When I examine the tree for this xmlDoc, here is what I see:

```
<p>
  "Here is text "
  <b>bold</b>
  <i>italic</i>
</p>
```

That is: the space between the  and  elements has been lost. What should appear is:

```
<p>
  "Here is text "
  <b>bold</b>
  " "
  <i>italic</i>
</p>
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Of course, I could evade the problem pretty simply, by having the xml thus: <p>Here is text <b>bold </b><i>italic</b></p>. That is: move the space to inside the preceding (or following) element. But this is just inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the problem is the erroneous XML (mismatched start and end tags on the <i> element).

When I try this out in Safari:

```
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("<p>Here is text <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>", 'text/xml');
```

.. I see a " " Text node for the third of the four child nodes of the <p> element.

Comment: No , that is not the problem. That was an error in the original question, but not in the code I actually worked with (as shown by the xmlDoc tree cited). It is quite possible that Safari works, but Chrome (which I was using) does not. It's also clear from W3C documentation that the implementations SHOULD deal with white space as I suggest. So maybe it is just an error in Chrome's implementation. (Old XML, and indeed SGML, hands will recognize this question of white space treatment as one of the hoary old chestnuts of the document encoding world.)

Comment: Just tried this with Safari 11.0, running in MacOS 10.12.6. Still the same. I do NOT get a text node for the third child of the <p>; there are actually only three child nodes.

Comment: However: Firefox DOES treat the white space between elements as a text node. Hooray.

Comment: @PeterRobinson Can you post an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I created a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/njp9qtkc/ I see: The <p> element has 4 child nodes.
The third child node has type: 3 (TEXT_NODE) Its nodeValue is: " "